# npm ignores "allowedNonPeerDependencies" option

Tags: angular, npm, dependency-management

I've made a component library in Angular. This library uses the package `moment` internally, and I want that with a specific version to be installed along with the library. I'm not sure I fully understand how dependencies and peerDependencies work, but this is my setup:

```json
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "0.0.4",
  "allowedNonPeerDependencies": [
    "moment"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "2.29.4"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^14.1.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.18.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  }
}
```

This is done taking in mind that

- `moment` is *installed with the library*, and any application that uses the library should be able to use its own version of moment independently. There are no Moment objects passed from or to the components.
- The Angular version used in my library *should match the major version* of the application, as I don't know if the components will work with older versions of Angular
- Ideally, exported *Typescript types should be usable* in the applications that use this libary as well. Hence the inclusion of `eslint` and `typescript`.

### The problem

When I `npm build` my library, npm gives me an error `Dependency moment must be explicitly allowed using the "allowedNonPeerDependencies" option.`, despite the fact that I added `moment` in `allowedNonPeerDependencies`. This option seems to be ignored.

Why is this happening and how do I overcome this? I use **npm v8.12.1**.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue, so for future reference: `allowedNonPeerDependencies` should be declared in `ng-package.json`, not in `package.json`